# Как присвоить id?

Tags: jquery

Как присвоить id не известному количеству ul ?

```js
var idArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  while (true) {
    var randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    if (idArr.indexOf(randomId) == -1) {
      idArr.push(randomId);
      break;
    }
  }
}


$('ul').each(function(i, elem) {
  $(this).data('target', idArr.pop());
})
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 6px 0;
}

ul li span,
ul li a {
  color: blueviolet;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><span>Список 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Список 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Список 3</span></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Список 3-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Список 3-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Список 3-3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><span>Список 4</span></li>
  <li><span>Список 5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Но в этом случае ul остаётся без id, как можно решить эту проблему ?

Comment: Эмм... а рандомные числа для чего-то были важны? Почему бы не использовать просто сами i от for, которые и так друг от друга отличаются...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME ну к примеру имеем меню ...я может просто что то не знаю ..точнее в js я вообще ни чего не знаю ..но надо было в меню вызывать список по id и если его id сменится то сами  понимаете ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var idArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < $('ul').length; i++) { // !!!
  while (true) {
    var randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    if (idArr.indexOf(randomId) == -1) {
      idArr.push(randomId);
      break;
    }
  }
}

$("body").append(idArr.join(","));

$('ul').each(function(i, elem) {
  this.id = idArr.pop();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><span>Список 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Список 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Список 3</span></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Список 3-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Список 3-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Список 3-3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><span>Список 4</span></li>
  <li><span>Список 5</span></li>
</ul>
```

---

> этот после обновления меняется

Тогда просто:

```
$('ul').each(function(i, elem) {
  this.id = 'id_' + i;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо ...я почти так же делал ..но у меня не работало ...